# Is it safe to copy packages under site-packages to use on other machine?

Tags: python

Python packages usually be  located under

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/
```

After installation.

Some packages can be directly copied to other machines (same OS version) to use.

My question are:

1. If one python package was put here after installation.  Does that mean that we can always  copy it to other machine to use?
2. Will this cause some bug?
3. Some python model may have dependency on some C lib. Does those python model also can be copied to other machine to use directly?
4. Some packages like psutil, will generate some directory like egg- directory. Should I also copy these directory? What are they used for?

Comment: Some packages work perfectly, but some packages don't work.